# A real Lie algebra representation not satisfying Schur's Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

For $L$ a real Lie algebra $V$ a real representation of $L$, we cannot apply Schur's lemma since $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed. Hence it might possibly happen that $V$ has an $L$-module automorphism that it is not a scalar multiple of the identity. What is an example of such an automorphism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L=\Bbb R$ and $V=\Bbb C=\Bbb R^2$. Then the irreducible representation $\rho$ of $L$ letting $\lambda\in L$ act by multiplication with $i\lambda$ on $V$ doesn't satisfy Schur's Lemma. We have
$$
{\rm End}_L(V)=\Bbb C\cdot {\rm id}\neq \Bbb R\cdot {\rm id}.
$$